# Finding a particular principal open subset of $Spec R$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $V\subseteq U$ be open subsets of $X=\text{Spec } R$, where $R$ is a commutative ring. So $V$ is the set of prime ideals not containing some ideal $I$, and $U$ is the set of prime ideals not containing some ideal $J$. Then in particular, $J\subseteq I$. Then, given a prime ideal $P\in V$, and an $f$ such that $X_f$, which is the set of prime ideals not containing $f$, is contained in $U$, I want to find an $f'$ such that $P\in X_{f'}\subseteq V\cap X_f$.

But I'm not sure that such an $f'$ is guaranteed to exist: Since $V$ is the set of prime ideals not containing $J$, $J$ is the union of the principal open sets $X_j$ for $j\in J$. Thus, I only need to show that $P$ is in one of the intersections $X_j\cap X_f=X_{jf}$. If this is not the case, then P must contain $jf$ for all $j\in J$. Since $P$ does not contain $J$, this means that $P$ contains $f$. But I don't see how this can be a contradiction, since $U$, and thus $V$ may contain prime ideals that do have $f$ as elements.

Comment: If $X \setminus V(J) \subseteq X \setminus V(I)$, one can only deduce that $\sqrt{J} \subseteq \sqrt{I}$. As you noted, the (current) problem statement is incorrect - if it were true for any $P \in V$, then $V \subseteq X_f$. Where in Dummit and Foote did you see this?

Comment: It's problem 19 in section 15.5, and the point of the exercise is to construct a restriction homomorphism on the structure sheaf.

Comment: Thanks for sourcing. It appears that they are simply assuming $P \in X_f$, which is in line with the goal of the exercise. I think the problem (in the text) could have been worded better though. Good job spotting this!

Comment: Oh, okay. So can we always find a $P\in X_f$?

Comment: For any given $P \in V$, there is always an $f$ such that $P \in X_f \subseteq U$. This is because the $X_f$ form a base of the topology

Comment: Right, but since they started with a function involving $f$, I was asking if you can pick the $P$ based on the $f$, not the other way around.

Comment: Are you asking if $V \cap X_f$ can be empty? This can happen, e.g. if $V = X_g$ and $fg = 0$

Comment: Hmm, all right. So then how can you make sure their construction always works?

Comment: Remember that the goal is to show that restriction is a well-defined ring map from $\mathcal{O}(U) \to \mathcal{O}(V)$. For this purpose, one starts with a(n arbitrary) $P \in V$, and can choose an $f$ such that $P \in X_f$. Dummit and Foote simply neglected to include this in their assumption on $f$

Comment: But since $s=a/f^n$ is a function in $\mathcal O(U)$, don't we need to find a prime for $f$ to be able to restrict that function to $V$?

Comment: If $V \cap X_f = \emptyset$, then $s$ restricts to $0$ in $\mathcal{O}(V)$. Otherwise, proceed as before

Comment: Why would it restrict to $0$?

Comment: Please think about this first. You can post a separate question after awhile if you like (this comment thread has already gone on long enough)

Comment: All right. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chose $g \in I\setminus P$ and let $f^{\prime}=fg$

Comment: Why must $P\in X_{fg}$? If $f\in P$, then this doesn't work...

Comment: Sorry is $P \in X_f$ ?

Comment: No, all we know is that $P\in V$.

Comment: But $P\in X_f$ is implied by your conclusion.

Comment: Yeah...maybe Dummit and Foote made an error in this problem...oh well, thanks anyway!